# ¿Qué significa “hasta que reventase para siempre” en este contexto?

Tags: vocabulario, significado

La frase en cuestión se encuentra en la novela [*La barraca*](https://archive.org/details/labarracanovela00ibgoog/page/n20) de Ibáñez; “ella” se refiere a una mujer que se hizo prostituta a la desesperada.

> No; ella no era mala. Había trabajado en las fábricas, había servido á una familia como doméstica, pero al fin sus hermanas le dieron el ejemplo, cansadas de sufrir hambre; y allí estaba, recibiendo unas veces cariños y otras bofetadas, **hasta que reventase para siempre**.

Según el DRAE, el verbo [“reventar”](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WNPQLOZ) tiene cantidad de acepciones. La persona que tradujo esta novela al inglés optó por [“morir”](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4LpwmzezEXMC&pg=PT16&dq="ceased%20to%20live%20forever"), pero yo tengo mis dudas:

- Esta acepción es el número 16 de la lista, es decir, la última.
- El DRAE pone que reventar quiere decir “morir *violentamente*”, y no veo por qué ella tendría una muerte violenta.
- ¿No es redundante decir “morir *para siempre*”?

Al principio creí que la frase quería decir que la mujer seguía pasando dificultades hasta que no podía aguantar más, y entonces se decidió a hacerse ramera. Pero después me di cuenta de que el uso del imperfecto de subjuntivo (“reventase”) indica que el acontecimiento aún no ha tenido lugar.

Para mí quiere decir que la mujer continuará su vida miserable y llena de malos tratos hasta que pierda las ganas de vivir, se vuelva loca, sufra una crisis nerviosa o algo así, pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: Creo que quiere decir `"3. tr. Fatigar mucho a alguien con exceso de trabajo. U. t. c. prnl."` (aunque reconozco que el uso en el libro no es transitivo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo diría que es correcta la idea de que *reventar* sea sinónimo de "perder la razón o la salud completamente", similar (aunque con más fuerza) a *quebrarse*. El verbo *reventar* es muy expresivo y se presta a estas frases sin significado claro pero intuitivamente comprensibles. Varias de las primeras acepciones del DRAE son aplicables, si se incluyen usos figurativos:

> 2. tr. Hacer enfermar o morir al caballo por exceso en la carrera. U.
>   t. c. prnl.
>
> 3. tr. Fatigar mucho a alguien con exceso de trabajo. U. t. c. prnl.
>
> 5. tr. coloq. Causar gran daño a alguien.
>
> 10. intr. Dicho de una cosa: Abrirse por no poder soportar la presión
>   interior. U. t. c. prnl.

En la traducción dice *ceased to live*, lo cual no sólo parece incorrecto sino que además pierde completamente la fuerza expresiva de *reventase*. No es éste el lugar de proponer traducciones al inglés pero creo que podría ir por el lado de *till she broke down forever* o *till she was forever torn apart* o algo así.

Answer (score 0):

*Esta respuesta es suplementaria a la de Pablo.*

También preguntabas por el uso de "reventase" (el subjuntivo).  Voy a hacer una variante de la frase de Ibáñez:

> Allí estaba, junto a la ventana, hasta que llegase su mamá.

En este caso, el narrador nos describe la actividad del niño, que iba a seguir hasta que llegara la mamá.

La frase de Ibañez tiene una estructura similar.

Lo que capto de la frase es una actidud derrotista.